# No internet connection in Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04

So until yesterday my internet was just working fine, today it doesn't anymore. Nothing has changed in terms of updates or configuration since then.

I can't ping devices on local network

Hardware:
Processor amd athlon 64 x2 dual core processor 4000+
Motherboard: Asus m2n-mx se rev. 2.01g
Ram: 1GB

Ubuntu Server Version: 22.04

/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml file:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s7
      addresses
      - 192.168.0.75/24
      gateway4:192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        search: []
version: 2
```

I'm new to Linux. And English its not my main language sorry for errors if there's any

Comment: perhaps you can [edit] your question so the heading matches the body of the question on version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what changed is netplan. Please check here:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml
```

Your netplan file has significant differences. I suggest that you amend tor file to comply with the format, spacing, indentation, etc. in the template. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

You should connect immediately, but, if not, reboot,